# Recenty I Change my Project for Android 12 But i am getting manifest merger failed issue

Tags: android

[Here is my manifest.I added the tag but still i am getting the issue.I tried to add android:exported="true" but still it saying i need to add the tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQytv.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

change tab to "Merged manifest" (its on linked screenshot) and you will see which `Activity`, `Service` or whatever don't have `exported` attribute set. I bet it is some 3rd-party component, e.g. from library. thats a job for library author to introduce Android 12 support now (maybe check for update/new version of it?)